# How to deal with "status"="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" of google place API in android application

Tags: android, optimization, google-places-api

I am using **google place text search api** in android application

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=haldi&location=28.62470,77.3806&radius=100&sensor=false&key=myBrowser_key

in responce I received JSON of places according to query.

according to this document
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

**we can make 2,500 requests per day.**

But as I configure my application with **only one myBrowser_key** and If my application is being used by 1000 users then after 2 to 3 search per user ...my place search will not work.it will show **"status"="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"**.

**So how can I deal with this issue?
Am i using this service in a wrong way?
How can I use google place service in my application?
Is there any way to increase limit?**

Any suggestion..please help

Answer (score 2):

Refer this link [Google Places API Usage Limitations](https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage)

- By default, each app is allowed 1 000 requests per 24-hour period.
- You can increase the limit to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period by
  enabling billing in the APIs console, and thus verifying your
  identity. A credit card is required for verification. We ask for your
  credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be
  charged for use of the Google Places API for Android.
- If you expect to need more than 150 000 requests per 24 hour period,
  you should request an uplift as soon as possible. (This involves
  checking your app for compliance with our terms of service, and then
  completing a quota request form.)
- If the number of requests exceeds 500 000 per 24 hour period on a
  regular basis, we consider your app a significant user of the Google
  Places API for Android. We will be in touch to chat about planning
  capacity. You don't need to take any action until we contact you.

Comment: definitely he is not looking to pay bills for at this moment, rather he is trying to find out if they are any architectural ways to minimize the query count.

Comment: `If you expect to need more than 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, you should request an uplift as soon as possible. (This involves checking your app for compliance with our terms of service, and then completing a quota request form.)`
have you any idea how to uplift request qouta

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, you should try to cache the response places to some extent, so that you can serve your new request but with kind of same parameters for certain time period from your server.

This would result some level of reduction if some set of user were looking for the same query from a specific area.